# Nuxt js serve dev does not load when accessed remotely from another device

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Nuxt js serve dev does not load when accessed remotely from another device.

Locally it works perfectly.

However, when I access the tablet, the nuxt address is running. An infinite load is shown.

```
server: {
    host: '0',
    port: '3030',
    https: {
      key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'server.key')),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'server.crt'))
    }
  }
```

Tried with and without https and the scenario is the same.

This error is shown after a long time of loading.

> https://10.0.0.108:3030/_nuxt/commons/app.js
> net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200

Someone could help. I am very grateful for the attention of the community.
Strong hug

Comment: It works fine for me, could you try with only `host: '0.0.0.0'`? Otherwise, do you have a [repro] or a Github repo?

Comment: By "accessed remotely", do you mean the tablet on the same network tries to access the Nuxt app which is on your PC / Laptop? If so, have you checked if your firewall is blocking port 3030?

Comment: @Colint - Yes, it's on the same network. I thought it was the firewall, but it's not. Because I use another service with AdonisJS and it works.

Comment: @kissu -same scenario

Comment: The connection is established. The loading icon is displayed. It just doesn't load the application. In this case, I believe it's not a firewall

Comment: Probably an error in the code so. Try maybe a simpler page somewhere. You maybe have a middleware or alike.

Comment: Otherwise, a [repro] can always help.

Comment: @kissu I tried using a clean install and the error still persists. Client-side does not render

Comment: Do you have a Github repo? Could you try in another wifi network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

It was some anomaly in the network settings. I used the windows network reset option and it worked.

Thank you all for your attention.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own question when possible.